# error: Unknown module(s) in QT: qml quick

Tags: qt, qml, embedded

**error: Unknown module(s) in QT: qml quick**

I do see quite few relevant topics, but none of them solves my problem.

I have Qt CReator 4.5.2 and QT 5.9.5.

While building the QT's virtual keyboard example, I run into this issue. The host environment is Ubuntu 14.04.4 and for it, the example builds and runs properly. However when I try to build it for my target, a TI board, I have run into this issue. I understand my build for cross compiling QT is fine. I have built qtdeclarative module as well.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer at the [link](https://forum.qt.io/topic/70166/unknown-module-s-in-qt-qml-quick/4)
The last comment helped.

It is suggested to used the qmake from sysroot instead of build folder; in my case it was 
/home/abu/targetfs/usr/local/qt595/bin/qmake
Now at least it builds for target.